# How to pull the artifacts from nexus in bamboo deployment?

Tags: maven, bamboo

Were you able to get anywhere with figuring out how to get Bamboo to pull artifacts from Nexus using the maven 3.x artifact download?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the version number available, possibly in a property file that can be injected into Bamboo in a previous job or step.

Then use a Maven 3.x Bamboo Task with the Goal set to:

```
-B dependency:unpack -Dartifact=your_group:your_artifact:${bamboo.inject.version}:jar -DoutputDirectory=.
```

The `-B` indicates non-interactive of batch mode, `-DoutputDirectory` can be set to anywhere you want it.

You will also need to place your nexus URL as a [mirror](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) in the `settings.xml` file in the `.m2` directory of the bamboo os user.